# What to use for insulation around base of lens that covers light in oven?

Tags: oven

I pulled the lens cover off in the oven to change the light bulb and husband says that little wrap of insulation (going to assume it is fiberglass) was not in good enough shape to wrap back around the base of the lens.  Can I use a strip of fiberglass to wrap around the base or do I need to use something else?

Answer (score 2):

Appliance parts store (or the internet appliance parts stores) your oven brand and model number, and the magic words **oven light cover gasket** should get you a new one for a small amount of money.

*(unless you use one of the various rip-off suppliers on the internet, so shop around, because the person listing them for say, $25, is looking for suckers - don't be one, shop around before you click "buy now")*